# WindowsFormsHost content doesn't show when its given to a ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, contentpresenter, windowsformshost

I have `WinForm` controls I want to put in a WPF `DropDownButton`s(Extended WPF Toolkit) `DropDownContent`. Putting the controls to a WindowsFormsHost and that one is giving to the `DropDownContent` doesn't work.
The Winforms control doesn't visible. In the template the `DropDownContent` property is a `ContentPresenter`.

If I want to try this whole story with a common container (`StackPanel, Grid`, etc.) it works fine.

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DropDownButton has a Popup whose AllowsTransparency is set to true - see the template [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/83001#1914844). You cannot put a WindowsFormsHost into a Popup whose AllowsTransparency is true. You'll have to modify the template for the DropDownButton so that its AllowsTransparency is false.